# Build nested named list from list in R

Tags: r, arrays, list

I’m trying to prepare a data structure which I will need at later point in my script. Let’s say I’m in a graph domain and my nodes (sometimes only 1, but mostly 2 or even 3) have names (e.g., `"left"`, `"right"`, `"center"`). The names are stored in a variable:

```
origin_target_list <- c("left", "center", "right", "")
```

Given the list with the three items from above, I’m trying to create this data structure dynamically:

```
origin_target_combinations <- list(
  left = list(    # origin is left
    right = c(),  # target is right
    center = c(), # target is center
    unknown = c() # target is somewhere else / unknown
  ),
  right = list(
    left = c(),
    center = c(),
    unknown = c()
  ),
  center = list(
    left = c(),
    right = c(),
    unknown = c()
  ),
  unknown = list( # origin is unknown
    left = c(),   # target is left
    center = c(), # target is center
    right = c()   # target is right
  )
)
```

EDIT: The constrain is origin and target cannot be the same. Thus, every element in the `origin_target_list` plus "unknown" should be combined.

Similar, a list with one element: `origin_target_list <- c("center")` would only create the unknown case:

```
origin_target_combinations <- list(
  unknown = list(
    left = c(),
    center = c(),
    right = c()
  )
)
```

I know this is a complex problem, I working on a solution myself right now... I'll keep this post updated with my attempts...

Comment: PS: If you have a better idea for a data structure feel free to change it. Still at the implementing stage...

Comment: In order to have a better idea, we would have to know what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as follows

```r
# assign function to create the list
create_list <- function(args, val = c())
  setNames(
    lapply(args, function(x)
      setNames(rep(list(val), length(args) - 1L), setdiff(args, x))), 
    args)

# use the function
str(create_list(c("left", "center", "right", "unknown")))
#R> List of 4
#R>  $ left  :List of 3
#R>   ..$ center: NULL
#R>   ..$ right : NULL
#R>   ..$ unknown: NULL
#R>  $ center:List of 3
#R>   ..$ left  : NULL
#R>   ..$ right : NULL
#R>   ..$ unknown: NULL
#R>  $ right :List of 3
#R>   ..$ left  : NULL
#R>   ..$ center: NULL
#R>   ..$ unknown: NULL
#R>  $ unknown:List of 3
#R>   ..$ left  : NULL
#R>   ..$ center: NULL
#R>   ..$ right : NULL

# you can change the type and the element names like so
str(create_list(c("cat", "dog", "bird"), numeric()))
#R> List of 3
#R>  $ cat :List of 2
#R>   ..$ dog : num(0) 
#R>   ..$ bird: num(0) 
#R>  $ dog :List of 2
#R>   ..$ cat : num(0) 
#R>   ..$ bird: num(0) 
#R>  $ bird:List of 2
#R>   ..$ cat: num(0) 
#R>   ..$ dog: num(0)
```

Comment: Also a nice solution. Thank you!

Comment: Working out of the box!

Answer (score 1):

This function should do what you try to do. But you have to fill the list elements with something more than just an empty vector as they are removed again if they are empty. So, I fill them with a vector containing a single NA:

```
make_dynlist = function(nodes){
  l = list("unknown"=list("right"=c(NA),
                          "left"=c(NA),
                          "center"=c(NA)))
  if(length(nodes)>1){
    for(n in c(nodes)){
      l[[n]]=list()
      for(d in nodes){
        if(n!=d){
          l[[n]][[d]]=c(NA)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  return(l)
}
```

The output would be:

```
> make_dynlist(c("left", "center", "right"))
$unknown
$unknown$right
[1] NA

$unknown$left
[1] NA

$unknown$center
[1] NA


$left
$left$center
[1] NA

$left$right
[1] NA


$center
$center$left
[1] NA

$center$right
[1] NA


$right
$right$left
[1] NA

$right$center
[1] NA


> make_dynlist(c("center"))
$unknown
$unknown$right
[1] NA

$unknown$left
[1] NA

$unknown$center
[1] NA
```

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my question to actually include `unknown` to be available for the target. But this is looking good so far! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple implementation using `lapply`:

```r
make_list <- function(branches)
{
  setNames(lapply(branches, function(origin)
  {
    blank <- list(left = c(), right = c(), center = c(), unknown = c())
    blank[!(names(blank) %in% origin)]
  }), branches)
}
```

Yielding

```r
make_list(c("left", "right", "center", "unknown"))
#> $left
#> $left$right
#> NULL
#> 
#> $left$center
#> NULL
#> 
#> $left$unknown
#> NULL
#> 
#> 
#> $right
#> $right$left
#> NULL
#> 
#> $right$center
#> NULL
#> 
#> $right$unknown
#> NULL
#> 
#> 
#> $center
#> $center$left
#> NULL
#> 
#> $center$right
#> NULL
#> 
#> $center$unknown
#> NULL
#> 
#> 
#> $unknown
#> $unknown$left
#> NULL
#> 
#> $unknown$right
#> NULL
#> 
#> $unknown$center
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is clever!